# Cannot install @angular/cli on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, angular-cli

When I execute command: `npm install -g @angular/cli` I get an error:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/my_user_name/.npm/_logs/2017-07-13T13_36_06_285Z-debug.log
```

And then I tried to execute command: `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` but I got an error:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/ng
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local/bin
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/ng
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/my_user_name/.npm/_logs/2017-07-13T13_39_01_642Z-debug.log
```

How can I install Angular-CLI if even sudo priviliges are not sufficient?

Comment: Try to remove /usr/local/bin/ng manualy (as root)

Comment: I do it and now I get an error which is described https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6848 but solution doesn't work in my example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a write issue.

You have two options to use sudo (not the best option) or change the folder owner.

1. `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`
2. `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Check content symlink path eventually reinstall duplicity a set rights.